# Bind DNS configuration is not showing A record for domain

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, ubuntu-20.04

I'm new to DNS setup and followed several instructions on setting up Bind DNS. Below is my zone file:

```
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     sandbox.svr. root.viper.sandbox.svr. (
                              13        ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;

; Name servers
@       IN      NS      sandbox.svr.
@       IN      A       192.168.1.7
; A records for name servers

viper.sandbox.svr   IN  A       192.168.1.7
viper           IN      A       192.168.1.7


;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA    viper.sandbox.svr. root.sandbox.svr. (
                              11        ;Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;

; name servers - NS Records

@       IN      NS      viper.sandbox.svr.

; PTR Records
10      IN      PTR     viper.sandbox.svr.
```

When I run

```
dig sandbox.svr
```

It doesn't return any A record.

but when I test with:

```
  dig viper.sandbox.svr
```

it does return A records:

```
root@viper:/var/log# dig viper.sandbox.svr

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> viper.sandbox.svr
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 489
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;viper.sandbox.svr.     IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
viper.sandbox.svr.  0   IN  A   192.168.1.7

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Fri Oct 16 20:16:56 WAT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 62
```

What I could I be doing wrong? My config is for a local environment and running on Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop.

Please see the syslog output below.

```
  
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [32768, 60999]
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [32768, 60999]
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: listening on IPv4 interface lo, 127.0.0.1#53
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: listening on IPv4 interface enp0s31f6, 192.168.1.7#53
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: listening on IPv4 interface virbr0, 192.168.122.1#53
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: listening on IPv4 interface br-048207a4c5eb, 172.19.0.1#53
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: listening on IPv4 interface br-22b8ad392785, 172.23.0.1#53
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: listening on IPv4 interface br-48aff5a17a13, 172.18.0.1#53
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: listening on IPv4 interface br-7ce2fd66ca47, 172.21.0.1#53
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: listening on IPv4 interface br-c5039c7c4806, 172.20.0.1#53
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: listening on IPv4 interface docker0, 172.17.0.1#53
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: listening on IPv4 interface br-c89505e1a15e, 172.22.0.1#53
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: unable to set effective uid to 0: Operation not permitted
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: generating session key for dynamic DNS
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: unable to set effective uid to 0: Operation not permitted
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: sizing zone task pool based on 7 zones
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: none:100: 'max-cache-size 90%' - setting to 14184MB (out of 15760MB)
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: obtaining root key for view _default from '/etc/bind/bind.keys'
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: set up managed keys zone for view _default, file 'managed-keys.bind'
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: none:100: 'max-cache-size 90%' - setting to 14184MB (out of 15760MB)
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: configuring command channel from '/etc/bind/rndc.key'
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: command channel listening on 127.0.0.1#953
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: configuring command channel from '/etc/bind/rndc.key'
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: couldn't add command channel ::1#953: address not available
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: managed-keys-zone: loaded serial 40
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: zone 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 11
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: zone sandbox.svr/IN: loaded serial 197
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: all zones loaded
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: running
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: zone sandbox.svr/IN: sending notifies (serial 197)
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: address not available resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:200::b#53
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: address not available resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:1::53#53
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: address not available resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:2::c#53
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: address not available resolving './NS/IN': 2001:503:c27::2:30#53
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: address not available resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:2d::d#53
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: address not available resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:12::d0d#53
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: address not available resolving './NS/IN': 2001:503:ba3e::2:30#53
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: address not available resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:2f::f#53
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: address not available resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:9f::42#53
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: address not available resolving './NS/IN': 2001:7fe::53#53
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: address not available resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:a8::e#53
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: address not available resolving './NS/IN': 2001:7fd::1#53
Oct 18 08:52:59 viper named[312379]: address not available resolving './NS/IN': 2001:dc3::35#53
Oct 18 08:53:00 viper named[312379]: managed-keys-zone: Key 20326 for zone . is now trusted (acceptance timer complete)
Oct 18 08:53:00 viper named[312379]: resolver priming q
```

I tried to troubleshoot by removing my internet connection and noticed that dig responded with the A records but once connected to the intenet, it doesn't. Is there a way to make the **local** DNS resolve for local query and forward public name to say google dns server?

Comment: Never use `dig` without the `@` argument to specify exactly which nameserver you want to query.... If you change zonefile content also remember to increase the SOA serial and signal the change to your nameserver, otherwise it won't pick it.

Comment: The zone file that you show says that the serial for the `sandbox.svr` zone is `13` but the log output says that the serial is `197`. Are you looking at the same zone file that is actually used? Also, for completeness could you include the `dig` output from the error case as well in case the type of response suggests anything about what is up?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist the zone file was my first test. I updated the serial after every update.

Comment: @ojoma Ok? Does it otherwise match what we are looking at? (If the question is based on the behavior with the 197 data, include the serial 197 data rather than old data from serial 13)

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Yes. It matches with the log file I posted here.

Comment: Do I need to add any entry to the hosts file?

Comment: Can you please provide the correct zone file? Yours also has two SOA records? Please also include the `named.conf` file so we know how you are loading the zone data.

Answer (score -1):

Please add:

@           IN      A       192.168.1.7

Then it will answer for pure domain query, without hostname.

Thanks,

Comment: It is already there!

Comment: Are you sure that zone is loaded correctly in Bind? No errors in logs?

Comment: or try to add (remember about dot): sandbox.svr.        IN  A       192.168.1.7

Comment: Using `@` or `sandbox.svr.` is completely the same thing.